# Apache not receiving/handling some HTTP requests

Tags: node.js, apache

I'm running two Apache servers (different instances)

1: running FreeScout app (https://freescout.net)

2: running NodeJS app (newer)

On both Apache is responsible for SSL termination using LetsEncrypt certificates.

Both from time to time losing some of the requests (not receiving them/or not handling them properly). In FreeScout app it causes the app to stop sending emails and etc, and in NodeJS app I see that the app doesn't receive that request thus nothing happens.

It doesn't happen often, but it does from time to time.
I'm running those instances on Linode if that matters, both on Ubuntu 22.04LTS.

Any help debugging, fixing this would be greatly appreciated.